# Could not load file or l'assembly 'Microsoft.Win32.Primitives

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

I'm transferring my IIS-based API projects to a landline server in Germany with IPv4 and IPv6 addressing. After IIS has been installed and set up as the old server continues to receive this error.

APIs are developed in C # Visual Studio and are mostly .aspx pages

New server configurations:
- Windows Server 2012 R2
- Microsoft .NET Framework: 4.0.30319; Version of ASP.NET:4.7.2053.0

[image: This is the error.]

Comment: Is the file in the `bin` location?

Comment: Yes: "D:\Progetti\<ProjectName>\CRV.API\bin\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives"

Answer (score 0):

Delete bin and obj folder in your project folder, then rebuild the project.
it worked for me.